# Optimal setting of class inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass

I'm doing a practical college work about class inheritance. My problem is two of the three subclasses have a common method that it's not present in the third, so I don't know if is best to add this method in the superclass without implemetation (It's a void method) or implements It separately in both classes. What way is best to implement it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
-- Base
    -- Base With Common Method
         -- Class 1
         -- Class 2
    -- Class 3
```

In Java it would be something like:

```
public class A {
}
public class B extends A {
    public void commonMethod() { }
}
public class Class1 extends B {
}
public class Class2 extends B {
}
public class Class3 extends A {
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't use inheritance purely on implementation and reuse as the criteria. Choose it if you really has a true **"is a"** relationship within the context of domain you are modelling. Share the domain you are trying to model for more specific help.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is to add another abstraction for the two base classes, and have one general abstraction for all subclasses.

For example:

```
      Dog
      Cat
      Bird

      Dog -> FourLegs -> Animal 
      Cat -> FourLegs -> Animal 
      Bird -> Animal
```

"->" can be extends or implements (abstract class or interface)

In any case do not add four legs to the bird just because its convenient :)

Answer (score 1):

You could add the method in the base class. The subclasses would overload this method if they implement it else use the base class method only.

```
Smthng like:
Base class: methoda()
SubClass1: methoda() --overloaded
SubClass2: methoda() --second overloaded version
SubClass3: no Implementation --used methoda() of baseclass as no implementation given.
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the thought of Pangea, always try to favor **composition over inheritance** if the relationship is not an "is a".